# Know if template parameter is const char* at compile time?

Tags: c++

i want to know at compile time if a template parameter is const char*, example :

```
static_assert(!is_pointer_to_const_char("test"));
```

will assert.

Thanks !

Comment: std::is_same<T,const char*>

Comment: I tried and not working.

Comment: What do you mean by saying - const char *?

Comment: I mean "anything" like this.

Comment: so should it fail also on string.c_str() or only on "somestring"?

Answer (score 2):

Hard-coded string in your example, is not "const char *", but array of "const char[N]". You need to handle this case especially:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr bool is_pointer_to_const_char(T(&)[N]) 
{ 
    return std::is_same_v<const char, T>;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_pointer_to_const_char(T &&) 
{ 
    return std::is_same_v<const char *, T>;
}


int main()
{
    string s1 = "str";

    static_assert(!is_pointer_to_const_char(123)); //NOT ASSERTED
    static_assert(!is_pointer_to_const_char("123")); //ASSERTED!
    static_assert(!is_pointer_to_const_char(s1.c_str())); //ASSERTED!
}
```

Comment: what's difference of std::is_same_v and std::is_same ?

Comment: @nonock: `std::is_same_v<T, U>` == `std::is_same<T, U>::value`.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::is_same` does exactly what you ask:

```
std::cout << std::is_same<const char*, const char*>::value;
std::cout << std::is_same<const char*, const char>::value;
std::cout << std::is_same<const char*, char*>::value;
std::cout << std::is_same<const char*, const unsigned char*>::value;
std::cout << std::is_same<const char*, const signed char*>::value;
std::cout << std::is_same<const char*, const volatile char*>::value;
```

The output of this code fragment is **100000**.

There is one caveat with `const signed char*` and `const unsigned char*`: these types are not the same as `const char*`. You decide if that is what you need.

Regarding the usage in template, here is a sample:

```
template<typename T>
struct C
{
    static int isParametrizedWithConstCharPtr()
    {
        return std:: is_same<const char*, T>::value;
    }
};

std::cout << C<const char*>::isParametrizedWithConstCharPtr(); // 1
std::cout << C<const char>::isParametrizedWithConstCharPtr();  // 0
```